# Date Conversions In Excel 2010

Tags: excel, excel-formula, date-conversion

I am looking for a solution to convert date data from a trade log into a different date format in an excel spreadsheet.

I currently have a date that shows 2007.01.03 18:01 (this cell is showing general and without date format).   I need this to be converted/changed to reflect m/d/yyyy h:mm

Does anyone have any solutions for this conversion?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the `01` from your example is the month, and the cell containing the date string is in A1, this formula should work for you:

```
=DATE(LEFT(A1,4),MID(A1,6,2),MID(A1,9,2))+TIME(MID(A1,12,2),RIGHT(A1,2),0)
```

Then format the cell as `m/d/yyy h:mm` using Custom Format and copy the formula down.

If preferred, you can then select the column containing the conversion formula and right-click -> paste special -> values to convert it to values instead of formulas.

Comment: Wow!! This was it.  I was extremely close, but missing just a few elements.  Thank you so much for the help and time!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option:

```
=DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1),".","/"))+TIMEVALUE(MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,999))
```

Then format the cell, as @tigeravatar stated, `m/d/yyyy h:mm`.

Answer (score 1):

To convert it to a "real" Excel date, you can use:

```
=--SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","/")
```

You can then either custom format the cell containing the date, or you can embed it in a text function to format it:

```
=TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","/"),"mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm")
```

*(I would have thought this might not work with windows regional settings of YDM, but it seems to work even then in some testing here.)*

Answer (score -1):

Good morning,

i) Use ctr + L to reemplzar. by /
ii) +1 ctrl - change the cell formatting in the custom tab in "Type" use the following format mm / dd / yyyy hh: mm.

Greetings is all.
CCB

By Google Traductor

Comment: =RIGHT(LEFT(A1;10);2)&"/"&RIGHT(LEFT(A1;7);2)&"/"&LEFT(A1;4)&" "&RIGHT(A1;6)